# Feed variable arguments to Docker ENTRYPOINT

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Say I have this line in a Dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/node_modules/suman/cli.js","a","b","c"]
```

what is the best way to programmatically populate a b and c? I am not sure how I can avoid hardcoding ENTRYPOINT.

There are some ways of getting around this. I could pass all my arguments in one variable, and hardcode that one variable, something like so:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/node_modules/suman/cli.js","--all-args=${x}"]
```

but I frankly don't know how to achieve either properly and I'd rather solve it using the first a, b, c pattern if possible. Anyone know of the way to do this?

Comment: It might be best to just override entrypoint using docker run...?

Comment: yeah that's what I was thinking, but don't you have specify --entrypoint with docker run in order to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change what the parameters are, why not pass them on the docker run line?

with `ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/node_modules/suman/cli.js"]`:

`docker run -ti yourimage a b c`

Arguments after your image name will be passed just like traditional arguments. Here, `cli.js` will receive them as `argv` arguments.

Use double quotes on the docker run command `"` if you want single arguments containing spaces to be properly handled.

I can also suggest you to use a [proper entrypoint for Docker](https://github.com/kerfab/docker-entrypoint), so that a few more things like CTR+C and STOP signals as well as programmatic features are handled better.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this, it seems best to simply omit the ENTRYPOINT line in the Dockerfile altogether and then pass in the --entrypoint value using `docker run`, like so:

```
docker run --entrypoint="/usr/src/app/node_modules/suman/cli.js" --name  ${container_name} ${image_tag} ${argz}
```

You can read about overriding entrypoint here:

https://medium.com/@oprearocks/how-to-properly-override-the-entrypoint-using-docker-run-2e081e5feb9d